# How to divert rain water from walkway?

Tags: drainage, landscaping, downspout

[image: brick walkway]

In front of our house, the downspout that drains half our 1200 square foot roof terminates right onto a brick walkway. Whenever it rains there is a puddle about 8 feet long so we need to walk on soggy grass to avoid it.

What kind of options do I have to divert the water away? Either burying a downspout under walkway and running corrugated pipe underground to the sidewalk (front yard down have a gentle slope away from house)? Or turning the downspout so it comes out behind this brick wall and use a downspout extender so that it sends water into driveway, which is sloped pretty well towards street?

Comment: The driveway sounds easy.  You want 1/4 inch per foot slope for the down pipe.  This will be good if you never get freezing temps and make ice on driveway/road(will have lawyers standing/sitting at the end).  That section of walkway looks like it might need some work.

Comment: dig a trench along the brick wall and install french drain pipe

Comment: @Traveler depends if there's a way to daylight a french drain.

Comment: Without a more comprehensive photo, have you considered simply re-pitching the gutter so that the downspout can be moved to a better location?

Answer (score 3):

Best bet is probably to put a drain pipe under the walkway.

I'm not too fond of the "along this wall to the driveway" option because that's also "along the front of the house to the driveway" and thus increases the odds of causing water problems in the basement.

Corrugated is usually the worst choice of pipe, as it clogs easily compared to smooth pipe. You shouldn't need to go all the way to the sidewalk - going ~20 feet away from the house (two sticks of pipe) sloping at 1/8" per foot (1.25" per 10 foot stick) to a dry well should be adequate - depending on soil conditions you might need a pop up drain on the drywell in the event that it overfills in large rain events.

Comment: I’m going with this  solution, adding a channel drain to walkway where water pools, 20 feet of pipe and a pop up emitter. Plenty of slope. I figured this way I can drain rain falling on the walkway as well As water coming out of the downspout. The only thing is, I just picked up pipe from Home Depot and got perforated triple wall.. Should I return this and get Solid?

Comment: Perforated is fine, so long as you put the holes down (water will flow up into them. Dirt will not fall in and plug the pipe. People who put the holes up don't understand water flow in soils, and do end up with pipes full of dirt in a few years. Specifically, the two lines of holes that are typical go either side of "stright down." A dry well at the end is worth considering.

Comment: i buried 20 foot of perforated pipe, with a square inlet and pop up outlet. it was about 8 inches of slope over 20 feet. last thing i need to do is concrete around the bricks
https://imgur.com/a/zUQUXlv